# Configure upstream for rebasing onto master in magit

Tags: magit

I have a forked repository. I want to configure my upstream so that I can keep my master up to date and rebase my feature branches. How can I do this?

`magit-version` returns `Magit 20160810.653, Git 2.6.4 (Apple Git-63), Emacs 25.0.50.1, darwin`.

Comment: By "have a forked repository" you mean forked on Github, or similar? Since you already "know how to do this in `git`", I think it would help clarify the question if you added example git commands to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [add a remote](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Remotes.html#Remotes) with <kbd>M a</kbd>. It will prompt for a name and url, and whether to set pushRemote.

You can then [fetch from all remotes](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Fetching.html#Fetching) with <kbd>f a</kbd>, or a specific remote with <kbd>f e</kbd>.

You can [rebase](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Rebasing.html#Rebasing) with <kbd>r e</kbd>, which will let you pick a branch, including the branch upstream.